# How to match a string ending with : or not in regex

Tags: regex, re2

I am using re2.h and doing partial match.

> Assume the input string is "123.45.34.5:8080". "123.45.34.5" and "8080" should be returned.
>
> Assume input string is "123.45.34.5". "123.45.34.5" and "" should be returned, too.
> How to write the regex? The following code does not work.

```
string portRegex = "[ \r\t]*([0-9a-f]*)[ \r\t]*";
string IPRegex = "([^ \r\t]*)^[^:]*";
string alertRegexStr = IPRegex + portRegex;
m_alertRegex = new RE2(alertRegexStr.c_str());

   bool match = RE2::PartialMatch(input_string,*m_alertRegex,
                            &cip,
                            &source_port);
```

Thanks,

**UPDATE**

Now the following code works.

```
string IPRegex = "([^ \r\t:]*)";

string portRegex = "[ \r\t]*:?[ \r\t]*([0-9a-f]*)[ \r\t]*";
```

But I have a question, why "**string IPRegex = "([^ \r\t:]*?)";**" does not work? What is the difference between ***?** and *****?

Comment: Search using `/:.+$/` and replace it with `""`

Comment: or `^[^:]*` .............

Comment: Sorry for updating the question..

Comment: Show example strings.

Comment: `:([0-9]+)` seems to do the trick for the first match.

Comment: Second match a regex must match something.. You can't return nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to capture both parts around `:`, you can use

```
^([^:]*)(?::([^:]+))?$
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/vK7pM7/1), results are in the capture groups 1 and 2. (The `\n` in the regex demo is used for demo purposes as the multiline mode is on.)

Regarding your question

> why `string IPRegex = "([^ \r\t:]*?)";` does not work? What is the difference between `*?` and `*`?

[It works](https://regex101.com/r/vK7pM7/2), but matches empty strings between each character and each separate characters, as it can match an empty string.

Note that `*?` is a lazy quantifier that matches 0 or more characters but as few as possible. It guarantees that the quantified character class only matches as many characters as needed for the rest of your pattern to succeed. In other regex flavors, you could use a positive look-ahead `(?=:)`, but re2 does not support look-arounds.

More details on lazy matching can be found at [rexegg.com](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#lazy_solution) and [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#lazy).

Comment: string portRegex = "[ \r\t]*?::[ \r\t]*([0-9a-f]*)[ \r\t]*";

Comment: Thanks. "([^ \r\t:]*)" can be used to find non-empty string before ":" if there is one colon. Otherwise it can return the whole non-empty string. "[ \r\t]*?::[ \r\t]*([0-9a-f]*)[ \r\t]*" can be used to return string after colon. If there is no colon, it will return empty string. But "[ \r\t]*:?[ \r\t]*([0-9a-f]*)[ \r\t]*" can achieve the same target in my case. Am I right?

Comment: I tried the above solutions. But if there is no colon, the second group match will fail. If this case, the RE2::PartialMatch will fail. This is not what I want.

Answer (score 0):

For input

> "123.45.34.5:8080". "123.45.34.5"

This regex returns **8080** :

```
:([0-9]+)
```

For input

> "123.45.34.5". "123.45.34.5"

This one checks if the char `:` exists.. since it doesn't it will return nothing :

```
(\:)
```